# Firebase user ID token: when does it change? And how to listen to the updates/refreshes of it?

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

## TL;DR

After/at when does `FirebaseUser.getIdToken()` return a different value? (When does expiration/update happen?) And how do I monitor/listen to its updates?

## The Setup

Our Android project needs to setup with a Firebase Project, where provides a bunch of APIs.

Most of APIs require user authentication token. We use Firebase User's ID token as header, like all of common projects:

```
Firebase.auth.currentUser?.getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener {
    it.token?.let { token -> callAPI(token) }
}

fun callAPI(token: String) {
    val header = "Bearer $token"
    // call out API
}
```

To manage functions, we split them into several parts, including User Repo and API modules. Due to this setup, I'd like to lazy-update the token (using an Interceptor etc.) -- whenever the token updates, updates Interceptor's header set.

However, I got myself lost in the documentation...

## What is ID token?

Firebase provides too many kinds of token, which confuses me a lot.
To narrow it down, I'd like to know which token means, or is equal to `FirebaseUser.getIdToken()`.

The most possible answer lays in [Firebase Auth User Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users):

1. ["Current user's access token"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle), which is refreshed when (1) token *expires* (when...?) (2) user changes password (3) user re-authenticate
2. The "refresh token" which appears in the same paragraph.
3. ["Firebase ID token"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens): It might be the one most obvious same to `getIdToken`. However the doc only pointed out that these tokens are "signed JWTs" and does not indicate when will it expire/update.

Which of above is equal to `FirebaseUser.getIdToken()`?

## When does ID Token expire/update?

As described above, if "access token" is equal to ID Token, does that mean:

1. ID token will expire (at when?) and it is a very common situation?
2. When user changes password, ID token will also update?
3. When user re-authenticate (including login, logout, register?), ID token will also update?

Also another most-resulted one doc in my search is Firebase Admin's [Manage User Sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions).

- The doc indicates that ID token is short lived and **last for an hour** -> Does that mean ID token always expire/refresh after around 1 hour?

The doc also tells when does refresh token expire, such as user deleted/disable/email or password changed. However I don't think those situation apply to ID token's expiration...?

## How do I monitor/listen to refresh/updates?

All of above questions can actually be ignored. What I care most is -- **how do I listen (detects) when the token is updated?**

As far as I know, only function I found is

```
firebaseUser.getIdToken(false)
```

Which returns a `Task`, and doesn't really works much like a lifetime-listener.

I found another one function:

```
Firebase.auth.addIdTokenListener(FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener { firebaseAuth ->
    // do something with firebaseAuth...?
})
```

However I don't know how to use it. Should I call `firebaseUser.getIdToken` inside?

I'm looking forward something like

```
firebaseUser.addOnIDTokenRefreshListener
```

but I can't find it. Is there anything I missed?

---

That's all of my question. Any information/clarification/experience will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care about token updates at all? Just call `getIdToken()` before doing something that requires it, so it's always up to date.

Comment: @Agent_L that's because (1) most of APIs requires header token so I wrote an interceptor to add it, but (2) I don't want interceptor to mess up with `FirebaseAuth` series, so I just make a public function to let others (ex. AuthRepo) to update the token.

Comment: I could always update token every time I send out a request, yeah that could assure it's always valid. But I'm still wondering if there's any chance to listen to token changes.

Comment: Rule of thumb approach with medium-lived, high-cost tokens is that you perform all requests with assumption that your current token is valid. Only when server replies with token error you refresh the token and retry. I don't think interceptor is the right place for such relatively high level logic, as you should share the refresh among all failed requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time has passed and I finally collected enough info.

Let's talk about Firebase ID Token:

- When does it expire/update?
- How do I monitor/listen to its refresh/updates?
- What is it?

## When does Firebase ID Token expire/update?

From

- Answer of @Frank van Puffelen
- [Firebase Doc for Admin: Manage User Sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions)
- [Reference of Firebase.addIdTokenListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-void-addidtokenlistener-firebaseauth.idtokenlistener-listener)

Firebase ID tokens are short lived, and will be refreshed when:

- after 1 hour
- user signs in
- user signs out
- user changes password
- user requires a force-refresh (by executing `getIDToken(true)`)
- *other firebase event, like "user changes"*

The procedure seems controlled by Firebase system. The time listed above might not cover all the cases.

## How do I monitor/listen to refresh/updates?

Due to the propose of Firebase ID token, you are not suggested to "listen to its changes automatically".

It's suggested to get token dynamically, by calling `user.getIdToken()`.

However, if you really want to monitor it, you may use `FirebaseAuth.addIdTokenListener`. Note that user (as well as `IdToken` ) might not always exist in this listener:

```
Firebase.auth.addIdTokenListener(FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener { auth ->
    Log.v("AUTH", "token Listener: triggers when user is ${auth.currentUser?.uid}")
    auth.currentUser?.run {
        getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.v("AUTH", "token Listener: current token is ${it.token}")
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.w("AUTH", "token Listener: failed getting token.", it)
        }
    }
})
```

Also note that calling `getIdToken(true)` would ALWAYS refresh ID token.

## Bonus: What is ID Token?

Firstly one have to know that, ID token, refresh and access token is **NOT** invented by Firebase. It's from the Network framework and protocol -- ID token is from Open ID Connect, and others from OAuth 2.0.

I'm not an expert in Network, so I'll just brief explain it from my understanding:

- ID Token: always encoded as JWT (JSON Web Token). Provides the identity of user. However it is not very safe as it might be stolen/copied, thus not suggested to be used in API.
- Access Token: no strict format (can also be JWT), but is limited, dynamic token generated (by server) from client request. Have many ways to keep safety, thus suggested to be used in API.
- (and a Refresh Token is sent from server, used by client/server, to refresh the Access Token.)

(I recommend a [comparison article of these 2 tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/), very clear and helpful.)

However, **there're differences in Firebase**. In all articles I found, they all indicate that: when you need an access token in Firebase, you should call `FirebaseUser.getIdToken()`. And it's dynamic, with refreshing mechanism, and you can refresh it from client.

Considered the definition above, I feel like that in Firebase, **Firebase (Auth) ID Token behaves more like Access Token defined in OAuth 2.0, not ID Token defined in Open ID Connect**.

That's all I got so far. Hope it helps the future googlers.

Answer (score 2):

ID tokens in Firebase are short-lived tokens that are valid for an hour after they are minted. About 5 minutes before the current ID token expires, the Firebase SDKs request a new token from the serve and start using that. At this point they also notify any ID token listeners that were registered by [calling `addIdTokenListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addIdTokenListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener)).

When the Firebase SDKs themselves need the ID token to send it with a call to the server, they call `getIdToken()` and pass the value along. Since most server-side calls are fairly short, the current ID token will be valid long enough for that call to complete, and is also what I'd recommend for most use-cases others may have for getting and passing the ID token. Monitoring the ID token or forcing a refresh are (or at least should be) relatively uncommon in comparison.