# Firebase token renewal

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for authentication in my Recat app and also I have an express server that serves a REST API, which has a middleware that uses firebase-admin to verify idToken that is sent from my app, to pass the authenticated routes

The idToken generated by firebase lasts for one hour and if the client is still on my app and hits any route that needs idToken and if the idToken is expired then the server just throws an error as unauthenticated, which is pretty good work, but this is not desired, I know my user is in there and just idToken is expired.

I'm using this code to revalidate the token, but it always returns the message: "error": "Authentication failed"

My code:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

admin.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
})

const renewAuthToken = async (user: admin.auth.UserRecord) => {
    try {
        // Renova o token de autenticação usando o usuário autenticado.
        const idToken = await user.getIdToken()
        return idToken
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error renewing authentication token:', error)
        return null
    }
}

export const middlewareAuthenticade = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const authorizationHeader = request.headers.authorization

        if (!authorizationHeader || !authorizationHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
            return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' })
        }

        const idToken = authorizationHeader.replace('Bearer ', '')

        try {
            // Verifica a validade do token usando o Firebase Auth.
            const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
            request['user'] = decodedToken
            next()
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.code === 'auth/id-token-expired') {
                // Caso o token esteja expirado, renovamos o token e prosseguimos.
                try {
                    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(error.uid)
                    const newIdToken = await renewAuthToken(user)

                    if (newIdToken) {
                        // Atualiza o token no objeto de solicitação para uso posterior (opcional).
                        request['user'] = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(newIdToken)
                    } else {
                        return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' })
                    }
                } catch (renewError) {
                    console.error('Error renewing authentication token:', renewError)
                    return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' })
                }
            } else {
                console.error('Authentication error:', error)
                return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' })
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error)
        return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client app is probably getting an ID token once when the user signs in and stores it indefinitely.  That's not going to work - ID tokens always expire after 1 hour.

The Firebase Auth client SDK automatically refreshes the token as long as the app is running.  Your app code should listen for updates to that token, and start using the new one immediately when it changes.

Use the [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onidtokenchanged) function to receive updates as soon as they happen, or follow the advice in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).

See also: [Firebase user ID token: when does it change? And how to listen to the updates/refreshes of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996056/firebase-user-id-token-when-does-it-change-and-how-to-listen-to-the-updates-re)